# how to enable chapterbib option in MIT template

Tags: templates, chapterbib

Can anyone suggest how to enable the `chapterbib` option in any of the MIT template, can download the templates and MWE from the [MIT Press Latex Guidelines](https://mitpress.mit.edu/latex-and-tex-guidelines).

Comment: If possible, can you post the MWE here and only add the link to the class in your question?

Comment: @Raaja sorry, it's a collections of many files, so only not able to post as MWE...